# How to make all scripts not run when api response error?

Tags: laravel, api, synchronization, command, laravel-5.6

I use laravel and I use command laravel to synchronize my database

My command laravel to call api to synchronize like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;
...
class MySynchronize extends Command
{
    ...
    public function handle()
    {
        DB::statement("SET foreign_key_checks=0");
        Vendor::truncate();
        Location::truncate();
        Item::truncate();
        DB::statement("SET foreign_key_checks=1");

        $requestContent = [
            'auth' => ['Administrator', 'www.Secret.com', 'ntlm']
        ];

        //call api vendor
        try {
            $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
            $apiRequest = $client->request('GET', "http://www.secret.com:1234/ODATA/ODataV4/Company('secret2018')/Vendor", $requestContent);
            $jsonResponse = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody(), true);

            $data = [];
            foreach ($jsonResponse['value'] as $value) {
                $created_at = Carbon::now();
                $last_modified_at = Carbon::parse($value['Last_Date_Modified']);
                $data[] = [
                    'id' => $value['Code'],
                    'name' => $value['Name'],
                    'last_modified_at' => $last_modified_at,
                    'created_at'=> $created_at,
                    'updated_at'=> $created_at
                ];
            }
            DB::table('vendors')->insert($data);
        } catch (RequestException $re) {
              // For handling exception.
        }

        //call api location
        try {
            $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
            $apiRequest = $client->request('GET', "http://www.secret.com:1234/ODATA/ODataV4/Company('secret2018')/Location", $requestContent);
            $jsonResponse = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody(), true);

            $data = [];
            foreach ($jsonResponse['value'] as $value) {
                $created_at = Carbon::now();
                $data[] = [
                    'id' => $value['Code'],
                    'description' => $value['Name'],
                    'created_at'=> $created_at,
                    'updated_at'=> $created_at
                ];
            }
            DB::table('locations')->insert($data);
        } catch (RequestException $re) {
              // For handling exception.
        }

        //call api item
        try {
            $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
            $apiRequest = $client->request('GET', "http://www.secret.com:1234/ODATA/ODataV4/Company('secret2018')/Item", $requestContent);
            $jsonResponse = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody(), true);

            $data = [];
            foreach ($jsonResponse['value'] as $value) {
                $last_modified_at = Carbon::parse($value['Last_Date_Modified']);
                $created_at = Carbon::now();
                $data[] = [
                    'id' => $value['Code'],
                    'description' => $value['Description'],
                    'vendor_code' => $value['Vendor_Code']?$value['Vendor_Code']:null,
                    'last_modified_at' => $last_modified_at,
                    'created_at'=> $created_at,
                    'updated_at'=> $created_at
                ];
            }
            \DB::table('items')->insert($data);
        } catch (RequestException $re) {
              // For handling exception.
        }

        // send output
        echo 'synchronize success';
    }
}
```

First I delete all data in the table using truncate. If it is deleted then it will call the api for the insert process to table

My problem is when an error occurs on the api server. For example, server is died or another error. It makes the data in my database empty because I've run truncate

How do I improve the script so that when an error occurs on the api, truncate is not executed?

What is the best way? Do you use try catch in the try catch to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at DB transactions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions

> If an exception is thrown within the transaction Closure, the transaction will automatically be rolled back.

So something like that could work:

```
public function handle()
{
    DB::transaction(function () {
        // your DB statements
        try {
            // external API calls
        } catch (SomeException $e) {
            // If for any reasons you want to catch the exception inside the closure
            // (logging maybe?), make sure to rethrow it.
            // Otherwise, Laravel won't know it needs to rollback the DB changes
            throw $e;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The link in your answer uses a database transaction. But your script using try catch. So what's the best solution? Can you answer according to my case or implement to my case. In my case exist 3 try catch

Comment: That wasn't my script. Just wanted to share the implementation of Laravel transaction handler pointing out the need to rethrow the exception if for any reasons you want to catch it inside the closure. I updated the answer, maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: Okay So if there exist error or no response from api, the truncate process is not executed right?

Comment: If the exception is generated inside transaction closure, all the DB changes will be roll-backed. So make sure your errors are exceptions (Exception/Throwable). And of course, test it. :)

Comment: I had try it. If there is no response from api or response error, the truncate process executed. It shouldn't work